# ASP.Net Core Razor Pages application not binding to property within model

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a login page, in the page model there is a property called LoginDTO (custom class of mine). Within this are only two strings - username and password.

On the login page I have a login form with two fields, you can probably guess what they are. The code is here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" asp-for="LoginDTO.Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" asp-for="LoginDTO.Password">
</div>
```

I fill out the input fields and hit submit (form method set as `POST`, I have an `OnPost` method in the page model to handle it), for some reason `LoginDTO.Username` is null however `LoginDTO.Password` is populated?? Therefore, of course, the ModelState is invalid and there is no `Username` string to use.

How can this be? I've tried renaming the variable and setting it as `value="@Model.LoginDTO.Username"` instead of using `asp-for`, neither made any difference.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE: I changed the `Username` property to `Email` and it's now started working?! Why do the name of these properties affect if they can be assigned values?!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I changed the Username property to Email and it's now started working?! Why do the name of these properties affect if they can be assigned values?!?!

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#complex-types

Then you need know that `asp-for` tag helper would generate the html like below by default:

```
<input id="LoginDTO_Username" name="LoginDTO.Username">
```

But you add the `name` property to the input element,so it would override the `name` property,it would render the html like below:

```
<input id="LoginDTO_Username" name="email">
```

So the model binding system could not find the `username` source.That is why it could work after you change the `Username` property to `Email`.

For your scenario,if you do not want to change the model property name,you could change like below:

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" asp-for="LoginDTO.Username">
```

Or just using the `asp-for` tag helper:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" asp-for="LoginDTO.Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" asp-for="LoginDTO.Password">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rena, I didn't realise that `asp-for` auto-generated the tags like that, I'm quite new to both Razor pages and web development (as might be obvious) and it being relatively new I've found it difficult to find many resources on it. I removed the `name` tags and let `asp-for` handle it, now it's working great.